# MS SQL DateTime value is different in a non-dbo schema

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, datetime, sql-server-2012, enterprise-library

In one of my projects, I experienced the following very weird behavior of MS SQL:

We originally had a table called 'Log' in the default 'dbo' schema. Whenever we inserted a record into it all was fine.

Later we decided to re-organize our tables, so we moved this table to a new schema called 'Logging'. Upon inserting a new record into this table the timestamp of the inserted record was 2 hours earlier than actual. (We are GMT+2, I don't know if that matters.) We were unable to find out what causes this behavior as while inspecting the timestamp in the C# debugger they were still correct, so something happened to them during insertion. We didn't touch a character in our code apart from the schema name changes.

Additional info:

- We use EF for most of our DB operations
- We use Enterprise Library (and so a stored proc) for inserting the log records, which simply executes an insert command.

Anyone has an idea of what can cause this to happen? After changing the schema back to dbo all was fine so it is pretty obvious that this behavior has something to do with what schema we use. Could it be that schemas can use different time zones and a newly created one has different timezone from DBO?

Comment: It does sound like some mixture of UTC and non UTC time data when there's the difference matching the timezone offset. Double check the data types and ensure they're not DateTimeOffset vs DateTime/DateTime2

Comment: They are the same as they were when we used the dbo schema. And they've remained the same now that we've returned it into dbo.

Comment: can u capture the insert command send to the database in profiler and show it to us ? For both schemas offcourse

Comment: Please post the revelant code (code used to insert the record, as well as the table structure (column name, types, etc..))